# Differentiate an exponential operator

Tags: derivatives, operator-algebras, chain-rule

I have an operator defined as: $$ \exp \Bigg[  \lambda \ \frac{\partial}{\partial R} \Bigg] $$

I'm trying to optimize this with respect to the parameter $\lambda$.

In other words, I'm trying to get an expression for

$$ \frac{\partial}{\partial \lambda} \Bigg[\exp \Big[  \lambda \  \frac{\partial}{\partial R} \Big] \Bigg]$$

I read about Sneddon's formula but that doesn't seem to solve the problem. Any suggestions on how I should approach this?

Comment: is $\lambda$ a functional parameter, complex parameter, or real parameter?

Comment: $\lambda $ is a real parameter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\exp(\lambda \partial_R)f(R) = \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{\lambda^k f^{(k)}(R)}{k!}.$$

Taking derivatives in $\lambda$ gives:

$$\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{\lambda^k f^{(k+1)}(R)}{k!},$$

or $$\exp(\lambda \partial_R)f'(R).$$

Comment: Isn't that the Taylor series for $f(R+\lambda)$?